# Function is_prime - Error

Tags: python, math, numbers, primes

This is a question from codeacademy.com, where I am learning Python.
So what I want is to define a function that checks if a number is prime.
If it is, return True.
If it isn't, return False.

Here is my code:

```
def is_prime(x):
    lst = []       # empty list to put strings 'False' and 'True'

    for i in range(2,x): # starting at 2 and not including x (number 1 is a divisor of all numbers

        if x <= 2:           # [1] see bellow the explanation
            lst.append('False')
            break

        elif x % i == 0: # if x is divisible by i(number between 2 and not including x)
            lst.append('False')
            break        # break, because we already know x is not prime

        elif x % i > 0:
            lst.append('True') # x is not divisible by i

    if 'False' in lst:
        return False     #  x is not prime - return False

    else:
        return True  # 'True' is in lst, so x is prime - return True

print is_prime(-2) # [2] I get an error here. See below
```

[1] - I made this condition because in codeacademy it says:
    "Hint
    Remember: all numbers less than 2 are not prime numbers!"

[2] - When I run, for example, 'print is_prime(11)' or 'is_prime(6)' it works ok. So I submit the answer, but codeacademy doesn't accept it. It says:
"Your function fails on is_prime(-2). It returns True when it should return False."

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Actually, this is a very good question, and you have provided all the information necessary to reproduce your problem - this is very rare for StackOverflow first-posters. So congratulations on that (and on your English as well). Glad to have you here!

Comment: I highly recommend http://pythontutor.com for visualizing execution:  if you go there, and paste your code into the execution window, you'll see why you get `True` for `is_prime(-2)`.

Comment: Besides that, you don't need to check all the numbers between `2` and `x` if you want to find prime numbers - `int(math.sqrt(x))` is a sufficiently high upper boundary.

Comment: Just +1 the question for the same thing as @TimPietzcker said... If everyone on SO could be like that, at your age... :)

Comment: Thank you everyone! You have really motivated me to keep going on this awesome world of programming...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's see what happens when you enter `-2`:

- `range(2,-2)` is empty, so the `for` loop never runs.
- Therefore, `lst` is still `[]` after the loop.
- Therefore, `'False' in lst` is `False`
- Therefore, `return True` is executed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realise it! This community is so helpful (:

Answer (score 4):

When `x` is `-2`, `range(2, x)` will produce an empty list.

```
print range(2, -2) # will print []
```

So, the loop and the if conditions inside the loop will not be executed. The last if condition will be checked and no `'False'` is in the `lst`. So, it returns `True`.

You can write the same program like this

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    prime_flag = True
    for i in range(2,x):
        if x % i == 0:
            prime_flag = False
            break
    return prime_flag

print is_prime(-2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realise it! This community is so helpful (:

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(x):  
    if x < 2:  
        return False  
    for n in range(2, (x)-1):  
        if x % n == 0:  
            return False  
    return True
```

Comment: Please consider to explain your code a bit, instead of just throwing it out to the public.